# Model not binding in Razor Page .cshtml through datatables.net

Tags: asp.net-core, datatables, razor-pages

I am new to Asp.Net Core Razor Pages and trying to build a sample application with Datatables.net.

I am trying to send data to cshtml page from .cs but can see the data. If I try to view the data in JSon format can see then but datatable is not getting binded with it.

Below is the code for the same.

Installed datatables.net and datatables.net-dt through Nuget Package Manager for Solution

I need the sample data to be showed under the tables with the UI classses binded with datatables.net

CSHTML.CS

```
namespace Razor_Harshit.Pages
{
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
   List<Employees> _employee = new List<Employees>()
    {
        new Employees(){ Name="Harshit", 
Email="abc@xyz.com",Gender="Male",Mobile="1234567890",City="Bengaluru"},
        new Employees(){ Name="Nitin", 
Email="abc@xyz.com",Gender="Male",Mobile="1234567890",City="Bengaluru"},
        new Employees(){ Name="Narasi", 
Email="abc@xyz.com",Gender="Male",Mobile="1234567890",City="Bengaluru"},
        new Employees(){ Name="Shivani", 
Email="abc@xyz.com",Gender="FeMale",Mobile="1234567890",City="Bengaluru"},
        new Employees(){ Name="Vineet", 
Email="abc@xyz.com",Gender="Male",Mobile="1234567890",City="Bengaluru"},
        new Employees(){ Name="Kaashu", 
Email="abc@xyz.com",Gender="Male",Mobile="1234567890",City="Bengaluru"}
    };

    public void OnGet()
    {

    }

    public IActionResult OnGetDisplay()
    {
        return new JsonResult(_employee);
        //return Page();
    }
}

public class Employees
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    }
}
```

CSHTML

```
@page
@model Razor_Harshit.Pages.IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" 
src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>    
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
        $('#table1').dataTable({
            pageLength: 2,
            ajax: "?handler=Display",                  ,
            columns: [
                { data: 'Name' },
                { data: 'Email'},
                { data: 'Gender' },
                { data: 'Mobile' },
                { data:'City' }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    
</div>
<div>
    <table id="table1" class="display" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Mobile</th>
            <th>City</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Results :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0h2S7.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwTsL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your code like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>    
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
        $.noConflict();
        $('#table1').dataTable({
            pageLength: 2,
            ajax: {url: "?handler=Display",dataSrc:""},                  
            columns: [
                { data: 'name' },
                { data: 'email'},
                { data: 'gender' },
                { data: 'mobile' },
                { data:'city' }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    
</div>
<div>
    <table id="table1" class="display" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>Mobile</th>
                <th>City</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You need to pay attention to the following points：

First,The passed parameter name will be changed to all lowercase by default.

Second,The reference to the jquery library should be before datatables.

Third,If you get this error: "TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function", you can call `$.noConflict()`.

Fourth,Change the ajax attribute to match the parameter type.

Fifth,You need to add the `<tbody>` tag, otherwise the header row will be replaced.

Test Result:
[image]